# Is it possible to generate VMAP as VAST 3.0 response for an video ad request?

Tags: admob, ads, vast, video-ads, adexchange

VAST and VMAP are two different standards but VMAP is complementary to VAST. I am building a system which is aggregates Ads from various sources and gives back to the client(asking for an ad). Some ad sources gives VMAP instead of VAST 3.0 - I want a way to combine VAST with VMAP or use them in conjuction w/o violating any standards/spec. I want to know how to achieve this, if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

Most (commercial) video players support both VAST and VMAP.

Either way, as far as my experience goes:

- A VMAP can only refer to a VAST, but never to another VMAP.
- A VAST can optionally refer to another VAST, but never to another VMAP.

If you would like to combine them together, all you need is to strip the URIs of the VAST files. You can then either serve them individually (a VAST at a time) or combine them in a VMAP.